# How to calculate mean average precision (mAP) using TensorFlow?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I want to use TensorFlow to calculate hashcode‘s mAP （mean average precision）， but I don‘t know how to use tensor calculations directly.

### The code which using NumPy is the following:

```
import numpy as np
import time
import os
# read train and test binarayCode
CURRENT_DIR = os.getcwd()



def getCode(train_codes,train_groudTruth,test_codes,test_groudTruth):

    line_number = 0
    with open(CURRENT_DIR+'/result.txt','r') as f:
        for line in f:
            temp = line.strip().split('\t')
            if line_number < 10000:
                test_codes.append([i if i==1 else -1  for i in map(int, list(temp[0]))])
                list2 = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
                list2[int(temp[1])] = 1
                test_groudTruth.append(list2) # get test ground truth(0-9)
            else:
                train_codes.append([i if i==1 else -1  for i in map(int, list(temp[0]))]) # change to -1, 1
                list2 = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
                list2[int(temp[1])] = 1
                train_groudTruth.append(list2) # get test ground truth(0-9)

            line_number += 1
    print 'read data finish'

def getHammingDist(code_a,code_b):
    dist = 0
    for i in range(len(code_a)):
         if code_a[i]!=code_b[i]:
             dist += 1
    return dist 


if __name__ =='__main__':
    print getNowTime(),'start!'

    train_codes = []
    train_groudTruth =[]

    test_codes = []
    test_groudTruth = []
    # get g.t. and binary code
    getCode(train_codes,train_groudTruth,test_codes,test_groudTruth)
    train_codes = np.array(train_codes)
    train_groudTruth = np.array(train_groudTruth)
    test_codes = np.array(test_codes)
    test_groudTruth = np.array(test_groudTruth)
    numOfTest = 10000

    # generate hanmming martix, g.t. martix  10000*50000
    gt_martix = np.dot(test_groudTruth, np.transpose(train_groudTruth))
    print getNowTime(),'gt_martix finish!'
    ham_martix = np.dot(test_codes, np.transpose(train_codes)) # hanmming distance map to dot value 
    print 'ham_martix finish!'

    # sort hanmming martix,Returns the indices that would sort an array.
    sorted_ham_martix_index = np.argsort(ham_martix,axis=1)

    # calculate mAP
    print 'sort ham_matrix finished,start calculate mAP'

    apall = np.zeros((numOfTest,1),np.float64)
    for i in range(numOfTest):
        x = 0.0
        p = 0
        test_oneLine = sorted_ham_martix_index[i,:]
        length = test_oneLine.shape[0]
        num_return_NN = 5000 # top 1000
        for j in range(num_return_NN):
             if gt_martix[i][test_oneLine[length-j-1]] == 1: # reverse
                 x += 1
                 p += x/(j+1)
        if p == 0:
            apall[i]=0
        else:
            apall[i]=p/x

    mAP = np.mean(apall)
    print 'mAP:',mAP
```

---

I want to re-write the code above using tensor operations (like `tf.equal()`、`tf.reduce_sum()` so on).

for example

### I want to calculate valid accuracy of images

```
logits = self._model(x_valid)
valid_preds = tf.argmax(logits, axis=1)
valid_preds = tf.to_int32(valid_preds)
self.valid_acc = tf.equal(valid_preds, y_valid)
self.valid_acc = tf.to_int32(self.valid_acc)
self.valid_acc = tf.to_float(tf.reduce_sum(self.valid_acc))/tf.to_float(self.batch_size)
```

---

I want to use TensorFlow to calculate hashcode‘s mAP （mean average precision）  this way（like tf.XX opreation）

How could I do？ Thanks！

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I tried to modify the method of calculating mAP values from the above code to calculate mAP values using tensor operations, but numpy's matrix operations seem to be different from tensorflow's.

Comment: yes the are different in some way. please make your question more specific

Answer (score 1):

You can just calculate the y_score (or predictions) and then use sklearn.metrics to calculate the average precision:

```
from sklearn.metrics import average_precision_score

predictions = model.predict(x_test)
average_precision_score(y_test, predictions)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to calculate average precision based on the validation set predictions, you can use the vector of predicted probabilities and the vector of true labels in [this scikit-learn function](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.average_precision_score.html).

If you really want to use a tensorflow function, there's a tensorflow function [average_precision_at_k](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/metrics/average_precision_at_k).

For more info about average precision you can see [this article](https://glassboxmedicine.com/2019/03/02/measuring-performance-auprc/).

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but what I need is to use hash codes as predictors to calculate mAP (as shown in the code I posted), so I may not be able to use these functions.